# How do we get the folder path of the file inside the workspace - Azure Databricks

Tags: scala, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm using the Databricks REST API to create the folder under the workspace, so that the folder will be accessed controlled as shown below

> URL - {{baseUrl}}/2.0/workspace/mkdirs

Body -

> {"path":"/dde9540f/cert"}

It's getting successfully created, I can see under the workspace and also list the files under the newly created folder using Databricks List REST API

> List API - {{baseUrl}}/2.0/workspace/list?path=/dde9540f
>
> Response -
> {
>
> > ```
> > "objects": [
> >     {
> >         "object_type": "DIRECTORY",
> >         "path": "/dde9540f/cert",
> >         "object_id": 142492279484620
> >     }
> > ] }
> > ```

Then I will pass the path of the certificate to the file system, so that spark can use the provided path to read the certificate under **/dde9540f/cert** and authenticate with destination file system to read the contents.

What is the valid path for the files under workspace? I tried using the below path

> /dde9540f/cert/client-keystore.p12

But ended with the error shown below

> Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
> /dde9540f/cert/client-keystore.p12

When I was using the dbfs file system, I was providing the file system path as below and I was able to read certificate successfully. I don't want to use dbfs approach cause DBFS is accessible by all users

> /dbfs/dde9540f/cert/client-keystore.p12

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: From where you are accessing this file? Is it from notebook or rest api?

Answer (score 0):

The rest api you used to create directory `host/api/2.0/workspace/mkdirs`,
will create directory in workspace not in `dbfs`.

I have created similar folder using this api.
You can see it is listed in `Workspace` not under `dbfs`.

[image]

If you want access anything inside this directory below are the ways.

In `dbfs` context you access it as below.

```
spark.read.text("file:/Workspace/dde9540f/cert/client-keystore.p12").show()
```

Without `dbfs` context

```
%sh  ls /Workspace/dde9540f/cert/
```

[image]

You are saying, it is successfully fetching when `dbfs` is used. Then you did not create the directory using above Api.
So the file is in `dbfs`  and you need to use `/dbfs/path_to_file` for accessing.

For more information on working with files you can refer below documentation.
[Doc](https://docs.databricks.com/files/index.html)

Comment: Can you tell me how you uploaded the `client-keystore.p12`?

Comment: Hi @JayashankarGS, I don't want to use the dbfs way of uploading the certificate. Cause anyone who has access to the cluster can access the certificate. I came to know that in workspace, we can implement/restrict the access. So I would like to use this approach. Using this approach what is the path that we can use, so that I can pass this path as the parameter to the file system

Comment: I didn't use the above api in the case of dbfs, it was /dbfs/mkdir instead

Comment: Also is this the better approach to dynamically upload the certificate and add the access control to it?

Comment: Also when I try to provide as /Workspace/.. I got the below error  Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Workspace/dde9540f/cert/client-keystore.p12: Operation not permitted

Comment: I have already given all users read access to the work space, still the jar not able to access it

Comment: check if you can access any other files in `/Workspace/` and where you are running this jar?

Comment: Sure, let me check. I'm running this jar in the databricks itself by creating a shared cluster